# How to return to the main program from a Pascal procedure?

Tags: function, pascal, procedure

how do i back from procedure to my main program?

here my procedure :

```
procedure sort_data;
var
   i, j, imin: integer;
   temp: TGame;
begin
   writeln('Begin Sorting : ');

   for i := 1 to dataa - 1 do
   begin
      imin := i;

      for j := i + 1 to dataa do
      begin
         if data[imin].price > data[j].pricec then
            imin := j;
      end;

      temp := data[i];
      data[i] := data[imin];
      data[imin] := temp;
   end;

   writeln('Sorting Success, press ENTER');
   readln();
end;
```

and everytime i done with that procedure, the app always gone exit.
I want to back to the main program everytime the procedure finished

here is my main program:

```
begin
   dataa:=0;
     
   textcolor(lightred);
   gotoxy(32,  3); writeln('DAJUNs Game Store');
   TextColor(White);
   gotoxy(26,6);writeln('* Admin View *');
   gotoxy(26,  7); writeln('----------------------------');
   gotoxy(29,  8); writeln('1. Show Data');
   gotoxy(29,  9); writeln('2. Add Data');
   gotoxy(29, 10); writeln('3. Search Data');
   gotoxy(29, 11); writeln('4. Delete data');
   gotoxy(29, 12); writeln('5. Edit data');
   gotoxy(29, 13); writeln('6. Sorting Data');
   gotoxy(29, 14); writeln('7. Filter data');
   gotoxy(29, 15); writeln('0. Exit APP');
   gotoxy(26, 16); writeln('----------------------------');

   menu := readkey;

   case menu of
      #49 : show_data;
      #50 : add_data;
      #51 : search_data;
      #52 : delete_data;
      #53 : edit_data;
      #54 : sort_data;
      #55 : search_data;
      #48 : exit;
      else writeln('You presses other key that not belongs here');
   end;
end.
```

so what should i add in procedure to make my problem solved
THANKS

Comment: Run the main program in a loop.

Comment: `repeat .... until menu = #48;`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to run the `case` in a loop - the best choice here is a `repeat until` loop because you would like to check the conditions after processing the body of the loop.

```
repeat
  menu := readkey;
  case menu of
     #49 : show_data;
     #50 : add_data;
     #51 : search_data;
     #52 : delete_data;
     #53 : edit_data;
     #54 : sort_data;
     #55 : search_data;
     #48 : exit;
     else writeln('You presses other key that not belongs here');
   end;
 until menu = #48;
```